How does one learn piano as a non-Western?
I can memorise my regional songs by using Synthesia, play arpeggios and stuff, and impress others, but I think I will never learn piano properly this way.
I tried taking Udemy courses but the songs I learn there are completely western oriented, so much so that I cannot play those song (such as Auld Lang Syne) in front of the public, even at home, as no one will recognize / understand those song and they would ask me to play something popular in our region.  This completely demotivates me which is why I begin to return to my old routine: memorise songs using Synthesia.

I think I understand your problem. There is a huge amount of piano literature in the western European musical tradition, and far less music transcribed for piano in other traditions. As the piano was invented in Europe, this makes sense, but does make it harder for people in other cultures to access sheet music for piano that they enjoy. I wish I had an answer for you because I know others in your situation. You might try to find a local teacher who can help you bridge the gap.

Maybe choose another instrument to start with, such as harmonium (I assume from your name that "regional" in your case means "Indian" or something related).  You are more likely to find instructional materials using your regional songs if you start with an instrument that is traditionally used for that style of music.  (For more on the harmonium in Indian music, the Wikipedia article is a decent overview.)

I have some suggestions, but first please edit to make clearer: What is your real goal? You say you successfully learn regional songs and impress people with them, and that sounds like what you want. When you say you "will never learn piano this way," I would argue that you are learning piano. Is the difference that you want to play these songs better? Or that you also want to play Western repertoire, but don't want to abandon the regional songs while you learn?

It would help to know what your 'region' actually is. The Indian sub-continent, I guess, but that only narrows it down a tad. Apart from songs, there must be piano pieces with no words (Fur Elise comes to mind)  that are recognisable for your audience. Maybe include some of them. There also may be many songs which don't translate well onto piano, with its particular tuning, slanted purposely at Western music and ears.

https://imslp.org has sheet music of many types. Maybe not much that's culturally relevant, but at least it's free

Also, why are you playing and learning it? One normally decides to learn to play an instrument because they like it and, usually, they like its repertoire. So, if you also like Western music and you enjoy playing it, that's your purpose, not impressing the audience. If, instead, you really want to play music that is more close to your "regional roots", that's a bit more complex, as most learning methods are indeed based on western music, because that's where the instrument was born and how/why it evolved as an instrument. You may need to use those methods anyway as a mean to your purpose.

not an endorsement, but first google hit: https://www.amazon.com/Indian-R%C4%81gas-Piano-Made-Easy/dp/1659067251

@user121330 I’ve learned there are some rich traditions that have been taught for centuries primarily through oral instruction, meaning some musical cultures just haven’t generated as much written music in the same way the European tradition did.

I agree with Tim. What is your region? Also, is the piano part of that musical tradition?

@ToddWilcox Agree. The two resources OP mentioned are pay resources and I may be in a different place in life, but always start with what's free when I'm getting into it - I only pay once I know I like it. Maybe an internet video search for the desired music would yield some oral traditions

By "Synthesia", do you mean this program?

@user121330 - if I had to rely on the internet before getting enthused, chances are I never would!

@GratefulDisciple It's most certainly that. It's quite controversial, because as long as it's considered as it originally was (a game) it may even be fun to some level. Unfortunately, some began to think of it as a reliable music and piano learning tool, without considering the consequences of that approach. While that misunderstanding may be acceptable for beginner learners, it's a completely irresponsible assumption for such "teachers". It was also discussed (and obviously criticized) at least twice here: https://music.stackexchange.com/q/110795 and https://music.stackexchange.com/q/110288

@musicamante I see.  Thanks for the 2 links talking about Synthesia, as I'm new to this program.  When looking at the Moonlight sonata example though, I notice that the MIDI source doesn't seem to be mechanically generated from the score, but from a real performance, thus preserving the artistry in the form of slight variations of key release & key down events.  So this tool potential to complement traditional teaching.  Example: 2nd mov of Mozart's K545 esp. at around minute 1:00 where you can hear the slight delay (agogic accent) before D5.

@GratefulDisciple Well, it may be partially useful to see these aspects, and while it may be interesting, it's also about the specific interpretation of a performer. Still, since the program is not able to clearly display the time relations between notes/rests and relative to tempo, the benefit of seeing those differences is quite limited, especially since there's no direct way to see the relation between the played notes and the written ones. In fact, if not properly guided, that visual approach may lead to misunderstandings of logic relations of rhythm. Besides, most of the times, the »

@GratefulDisciple » perception of these variations in rhythm and key pressure duration, can be easily achieved by listening carefully to the performance (except when the sustain pedal is in use, obviously). And that would even be possible with any basic MIDI based program that can show piano rolls. As said, and as I wrote in one of the posts above, that program may be useful at some level while starting to learn, but as the learning evolves, its value rapidly decreases and goes near to zero, if considered in relation to appropriate music theory and instrument learning.

I actually feel like I got slightly better at piano after learning some arabic music theory, because I am know thinking of groups of notes and moving between them instead of a rigid scale and going "off scale". This is where I learnt about it maqamworld.com/en/book.php. This in combination about playing ragas (which I know think of as two of those jins joined together) was quite fun. I also recommend playing along with music in your ears.

@musicamante "as the learning evolves, its value rapidly decreases and goes near to zero"  I agree with you there, just brainstorming about potential use of technology in music research, learning, and performance. See my comments in The Practice Room.

The technical aspect of playing is not material-specific.   If it's all the teacher offers, learn to play 'Auld Lang Syne' from notation.   The reading skills and playing skills are completely transferable to reading and playing any other pieces of music.
You say the songs you want to play are available on Synthesia?   But you can't find them in normal notation?   Can you give us some examples of the sort of thing you want?
Anyway, however you access the songs, you'll also be developing your 'busking' skills.  Choose a fairly simple song and work it out with just your brain and fingers.  Yes you can!

As @Laurence said, "the technical aspect of playing [the piano] is not material-specific".  Even in the Western world, most teachers now will tailor the repertoire to what the student is interested in, especially when they are younger.  Even the goal for the individualized piano lessons can vary:

some want to play standard Western classical pieces by Bach, Mozart, Beethoven, Chopin
some want to play Jazz where ability to improvise is a must
some want a general skill to play any piano sheet music (in the ubiquitous Western notation) of any genre
some want to accompany traditional church music service whether on-the-spot harmonization will be very handy
some want to participate in contemporary Christian music where they usually go by just words and chords only (sometimes with melody line).

But when you review the above list, I think the ability to read piano sheet music and play it on the piano will be the most beneficial; it's a very versatile skill that would be good for any pianist playing any kind of music.
So for your non-Western living situation, I recommend this:

Visit a local music store and ask whether there are piano sheet music for popular songs that you want to play.  If there is none, ask a local musicians to write it down for you.  Nowadays there are online websites like MuseScore where notating and sharing sheet music is very easy.  So the local musicians can use MuseScore to publish your region's sheet music, which then will be good for other piano students in your region.
Use Udemy to learn the general fingering and music-reading skill, and then practice using the sheet music you can find for your region's popular songs.
Find a local piano teacher who can guide you and take a few lessons from them before going to online courses again.  They can diagnose what skills you need and other piano playing factors that you may not realize are important to address.

There is always a chatroom, where I'm sure someone in the community (including myself) would be willing to notate a simple song in MuseScore (or other tools), if you would provide a YouTube / mp3 link.
Good luck!
